# .NET Regular expressions on bytes instead of chars

Tags: c#, .net, regex, boost, byte

I'm trying to do some parsing that will be easier using regular expressions.

The input is an array (or enumeration) of bytes.

I don't want to convert the bytes to chars for the following reasons:

1. Computation efficiency
2. Memory consumption efficiency
3. Some non-printable bytes might be complex to convert to chars. Not all the bytes are printable.

So I can't use [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=VS.71%29.aspx).

The only solution I know, is using [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) (which works on bytes - C chars), but this is a C++ library that wrapping using C++/CLI will take considerable work.

How can I use regular expressions on bytes in .NET directly, without working with .NET strings and chars?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a RegEx pattern you're trying to match?

Comment: @Nate Dudek, I don't see how is it relevant. I'm looking for a general regex library since I'm trying to parse complex internet protocols. Not a specific regex. If you really need an example see http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt for the different regex there (it also references other rfcs)

Comment: Actually, .NET does not support binary input for Regular Expression. I understand that you don't want to lose computing time in conversion, but if special characters is your only fear, you can convert your bytes to strings without a problem as .NET string are encoded using Unicode UTF-16. All characters will be supported.

Comment: @Ucodia, I know that I can convert every byte to a .NET char using iso-8859-1 (this is actually the only encoding that makes it possible). As I've said, I want to avoid that computation and memory inefficiencies.

Comment: Do you really need a full Regex implementation, or just a parser?

Comment: @David Lively,  I believe that in order to fully parse the protocol, I need a full Regex implementation, or a parser that pretty much implements a regular expression machine.

Comment: I'm guessing you are parsing protocol data. Personally I wrote a small state machine that parsed the bytes and would pattern match. It is  extremely readable despite being kind of long. How long are the patterns you are trying to match?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a bit of impedance mismatch going on here. You want to work with Regular expressions in .Net which use strings (multi-byte characters), but you want to work with single byte characters. You can't have both at the same time using .Net as per usual.

However, to break this mismatch down, you could deal with a string in a byte oriented fashion and mutate it. The mutated string can then act as a re-usable buffer. In this way you will not have to convert bytes to chars, or convert your input buffer to a string (as per your question).

An example:

```
//BLING
byte[] inputBuffer = { 66, 76, 73, 78, 71 };

string stringBuffer = new string('\0', 1000);

Regex regex = new Regex("ING", RegexOptions.Compiled);

unsafe
{
    fixed (char* charArray = stringBuffer)
    {
        byte* buffer = (byte*)(charArray);

        //Hard-coded example of string mutation, in practice you would
        //loop over your input buffers and regex\match so that the string
        //buffer is re-used.

        buffer[0] = inputBuffer[0];
        buffer[2] = inputBuffer[1];
        buffer[4] = inputBuffer[2];
        buffer[6] = inputBuffer[3];
        buffer[8] = inputBuffer[4];

        Console.WriteLine("Mutated string:'{0}'.",
             stringBuffer.Substring(0, inputBuffer.Length));

        Match match = regex.Match(stringBuffer, 0, inputBuffer.Length);

        Console.WriteLine("Position:{0} Length:{1}.", match.Index, match.Length);
    }
}
```

Using this technique you can allocate a string "buffer" which can be re-used as the input to Regex, but you can mutate it with your bytes each time. This avoids the overhead of converting\encoding your byte array into a new .Net string each time you want to do a match. This could prove to be very significant as I have seen many an algorithm in .Net try to go at a million miles an hour only to be brought to its knees by string generation and the subsequent heap spamming and time spent in GC.

Obviously this is unsafe code, but it is .Net.

The results of the Regex will generate strings though, so you have an issue here. I'm not sure if there is a way of using Regex that will not generate new strings. You can certainly get at the match index and length information but the string generation violates your requirements for memory efficiency.

**Update**

Actually after disassembling Regex\Match\Group\Capture, it looks like it only generates the captured string when you access the Value property, so you may at least not be generating strings if you only access index and length properties. However, you will be generating all the supporting Regex objects.

Comment: Your solution seems to work when the input is a string. My input is bytes, which I don't want to convert to a string. I'm not sure why I can't both - if someone has already wrapped Boost.Regex with C++/CLI I can have both.

Comment: Yes, what I am suggesting is that you use the string as a buffer and mutate it using your bytes. Where I am mutating it, you would use your byte buffer here. This is just a basic example of mutating a string, but it does mean you can have a re-usable string buffer for the regex input which you mutate with your input.

Comment: Nice idea.
But this means that every time I have new set of bytes, I'll need to copy them to the char array. This seems to be the exact same solution as converting the bytes to a string using Encoding, but with string reuse (which might be problematic when it comes to size limits and if I want to use two inputs in parallel).

Comment: Comparable outcome, but certainly not the "exact" same solution. Disassemble the relevant Encoding classes and methods and you'll see.

Comment: @brickner: Are you concerned about efficiency of copying bytes to a buffer yet want to invoke a regex engine on your bytes?  Do tell...

Comment: @brickner It very much looks like you are using the wrong sort of platform (i.e. .Net) given the various impedance mismatches: string handling, memory efficiency, etc. Use something like C instead.

Comment: @brickner: What's the reasoning for the focus on one area of efficiency to the exclusion of a more significant one? If you provide more detail or context the community might be better able to guide you and provide an answer that suits you, even if it's a correction in perception of the problem at hand, the big picture.

Comment: @jdk, I don't expect the community to read a few HTTP RFCs to see all the regular expressions that these RFCs define. Most HTTP parsers don't parse exactly as the RFCs define HTTP and I thought to write something that will enable users to get every bit of the RFC, including the exact parsing of the different fields and so on. I also want this ability for other protocols parsing.

Comment: @brickner I updated the code sample and included example regex code. Setting the length when calling match handles input buffer length differences.

Comment: @chibacity, what happens if in the same application, I'll create another string equals the original string (let's say before your code runs): new string('\0', 1000);
Wouldn't that create a reference to the same string? From what I know, in .NET all equal strings reference the same string. This can create very problematic behavior because it will make other strings mutate when mutating the string...

Comment: @brickner The general mechanism you are referring to in .Net is called "String Interning". String literals during compilation, and strings which have had String.Intern(..) called on them, are indeed added to a shared pool and are reference-equal. However, we are not using a string literal here, we are creating a new string so it will not be interned. You can investigate this with ReferenceEqual(strA, strB) or String.IsInterned(strA).

Answer (score 2):

Well, if I faced this problem, I would DO the C++/CLI wrapper, except I'd create specialized code for what I want to achieve. Eventually develop the wrapper with time to do general things, but this just an option.

The first step is to wrap the Boost::Regex input and output only. Create specialized functions in C++ that do all the stuff you want and use CLI just to pass the input data to the C++ code and then fetch the result back with the CLI. This doesn't look to me like too much work to do.

**Update:**

Let me try to clarify my point. Even though I may be wrong, I believe you wont be able to find any *.NET Binary Regex* implementation that you could use. That is why - whether you like it or not - you will be forced to choose between CLI wrapper and bytes-to-chars conversion to use .NET's Regex. In my opinion the wrapper is better choice, because it will be working faster. I did not do any benchmarking, this is just an assumption based on:

1. Using wrapper you just have to cast
   the pointer type (bytes <-> chars).
2. Using .NET's Regex you have to
       convert each byte of the input.

Comment: I actually know exactly how to wrap it, but I'm looking for a solution I don't have to write myself.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to using unsafe, just consider writing a simple, recursive comparer like:

```
static bool Evaluate(byte[] data, byte[] sequence, int dataIndex=0, int sequenceIndex=0)
{
       if (sequence[sequenceIndex] == data[dataIndex])
       {
           if (sequenceIndex == sequence.Length - 1)
               return true;
           else if (dataIndex == data.Length - 1)
               return false;
           else
               return Evaluate(data, sequence, dataIndex + 1, sequenceIndex + 1);
       }
       else
       {
           if (dataIndex < data.Length - 1)
               return Evaluate(data, sequence, dataIndex+1, 0);
           else
               return false;
       }
}
```

You could improve efficiency in a number of ways (i.e. seeking the first byte match instead of iterating, etc.) but this could get you started... hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I personally went a different approach and wrote a small state machine that can be extended. I believe if parsing protocol data this is much more readable than regex.

```
bool ParseUDSResponse(PassThruMsg rxMsg, UDScmd.Mode txMode, byte txSubFunction, out UDScmd.Response functionResponse, out byte[] payload)
{
    payload = new byte[0];
    functionResponse = UDScmd.Response.UNKNOWN;
    bool positiveReponse = false;
    var rxMsgBytes = rxMsg.GetBytes();

    //Iterate the reply bytes to find the echod ECU index, response code, function response and payload data if there is any
    //If we could use some kind of HEX regex this would be a bit neater
    //Iterate until we get past any and all null padding
    int stateMachine = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rxMsgBytes.Length; i++)
    {
        switch (stateMachine)
        {
            case 0:
                if (rxMsgBytes[i] == 0x07) stateMachine = 1;
                break;
            case 1:
                if (rxMsgBytes[i] == 0xE8) stateMachine = 2;
                else return false;
            case 2:
                if (rxMsgBytes[i] == (byte)txMode + (byte)OBDcmd.Reponse.SUCCESS)
                {
                    //Positive response to the requested mode
                    positiveReponse = true;
                }
                else if(rxMsgBytes[i] != (byte)OBDcmd.Reponse.NEGATIVE_RESPONSE)
                {
                    //This is an invalid response, give up now
                    return false;
                }
                stateMachine = 3;
                break;
            case 3:
                functionResponse = (UDScmd.Response)rxMsgBytes[i];
                if (positiveReponse && rxMsgBytes[i] == txSubFunction)
                {
                    //We have a positive response and a positive subfunction code (subfunction is reflected)
                    int payloadLength = rxMsgBytes.Length - i;
                    if(payloadLength > 0)
                    {
                        payload = new byte[payloadLength];
                        Array.Copy(rxMsgBytes, i, payload, 0, payloadLength);
                    }
                    return true;
                } else
                {
                    //We had a positive response but a negative subfunction error
                    //we return the function error code so it can be relayed
                    return false;
                }
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```